# C++ stack overflow when placing a big object in a collection

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I'm creating a block based engine and I was working on infinite loading.
I've edited some of my code to implement `std::unordered_map`. But I'm having trouble with a stack overflow exception. It's such a big object it can't be all stored on the stack. It's size is: `CHUNK_SIZE(32)^3 * WORLD_HEIGHT(8 amount of chunks in height) * 4(block bytes) = 1048576 bytes`. (And that * 225 makes up my world.)

I'm currently using this code: (I guess because it is temporarily created on the stack?). How should I implement this?

```
for(int x = 0; x < size*size; x++){
    loadedChunkContainers.emplace(std::make_pair(x, ChunkContainer()));
}
```

(I know you could allocate it on the heap with `new` but everyone always tells me not to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct that whomping big object in-place.
Thus, no copying / moving and only minimal stack-usage is neccessary.

Use [`std::piecewise_construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct):

```
for(int x = 0; x < size*size; x++)
    loadedChunkContainers.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            make_tuple(x), make_tuple());
```

Comment: Hmm, I still get a stack overflow.

Comment: @Duckdoom5 So, your `unordered_map` lives on the stack then?

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking, maybe its because the inner class is constructed on the stack? could that be the problem? I believe I use an array to construct the inner class

Comment: @ComicSansMS yes, I think. its created in the header file

Comment: Well, try to change it so that inner class is inplace-constructed too, that should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, awesome. I also changed the inner class array to a `std::vector` and now it works.